# OpenCvSharp KNearest FindNearest

Tags: c#, opencv

i am using OpenCvSharp to sole an image-Problem and now i Get a exception by following lines and using KNearest class.

```
        Mat results = new Mat(help.Size(), MatType.CV_16S);
        var resultAsArray = OpenCvSharp.OutputArray.Create(results);
        var lll = kNearest.FindNearest(helpAsArray, 1, resultAsArray);
```

The exception is following:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in OpenCvSharp.dll

*Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

I tested some varaints to create my outarray but get the exception everytime.

Some idea?

Thanks for your help

In other function calls I can work with OutputArray.....